# What makes a beer syrupy in texture?

Tags: beer, ale, taste, rye

I have recently brewed a nice rye ale. It turned out very nicely, however, compared to all the other beers I've brewed, it has a really syrupy texture and thickness to it. It quite dry but it isn't strong, ABV is 5.5%. The main malts were pale, rye and some wheat.

So I was wondering - what are **general influences** on the **thickness** of a beer? Is it just the malts (I'd guess the wheat malt is at least somehow responsible for parts of the syrupiness)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using today's highly modified malts, mash temp makes a lot less difference than it used it.  I'd say it's the rye.  I have made many, many rye beers and as the % of rye rises, the beer gets a thicker, more intense mouthfeeel.

Comment: thanks for the good answer - i'm accepting it as the "correct" answer, since i also guess it's the rye. I've read [this article](https://www.morebeer.com/brewingtechniques/library/backissues/issue1.3/hayden.html) that confirms what you've wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the temperature of the mash can give a thicker consistency to the beer as you move from 63-68 degC for you mash temperature the high you go the more dominant alpha-amylase will be. This cleaves off unfermentable tri-saccharides (three unit sugars) which give a full mouth feel, where as beta amylase which is most active ~63-64 degC cleaves single glucose molecules off the starch chains, giving highly fermentable wort and thinner bodied beer.

Also sometimes diacetyl can lend a buttery/butterscotch like syrupy feel to the beer.

Comment: nice answer, thanks! i forgot to mention in my question, that the beer is actually quite dry, so there arent that many "unfermentable tri-saccharides" I'd assume...

Comment: while technically correct, in the real world it just doesn't matter that much